# main() vs int main() in DevC++

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am using DevC++.

- when I write `void main()`, the compiler says main must return int.
- when I write `main()`, the compiler reports nothing.
- when  write `int main()`, the compiler asks me to return something.

My question is what is main() without int and void?why does compiler behave differently for int main() and just main()?

Comment: Are you targeting C, or C++ here? (The answer is language-dependent).

Comment: @Bathsheba I use DevC++ and write both C and C++ programs in it and this happens regardless of the C/C++ program.

Comment: my question is totally different from the question that has been asked and  answered before.I am not asking the difference between void main() and int main() .I am asking what do just main() means to the compiler.

Comment: The C++ standard says _"If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0`;"_ so _"when write `int main()`, the compiler asks me to return something"_ sounds odd if you're really using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Michael It does.This is what I am asking why compiler behaves differently for int main() and main()?

Answer (score 3):

In C, it's a C89 feature made obsolete in C99 and later: if the return type is omitted, `int` is implied. In C++, it is a compiler extension not supported by the language but supported by some compilers.

Comment: If int is implied then why it does not ask me to write a return statement?

Comment: The omitted return type and variable type is assumed to be `int` since [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#K.26R_C), back in the 70s.

Comment: @fahreen in C, the return statement in `main` is never mandatory. If omitted, in C99, `return 0` is implied and in C89 an undefined termination status is returned. C++ is like C89 in that matter IIRC.

Comment: @ouah but when I write int main() then compiler asks me to write return statement.Compiler behaves differently for int main() and just main().Is this a problem with compiler?